# How can I configure Ember's LSAdapter to not look in the root directory?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I've almost completed the Ember TodoMVC example but I'm getting stuck on using the [local storage adapter](http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/using-other-adapters/). I had the demo working until I tried to use the local storage adapter. This is what my `application.js` looks like trying to use local storage:

```
window.Todos = Ember.Application.create();

Todos.ApplicationAdapter = DS.LSAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'todos-emberjs'
});
```

When I swaped out the fixture adapter with LSAdapter I got this error:

```
OPTIONS file:///todos net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

So, I created the file `todos` in my root dir (as root of course), and now I'm getting this error:

```
OPTIONS file:///todos No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. jquery-1.10.2.js:8706
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///todos. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. index.html:1
Error while loading route: undefined ember-1.5.0.js:3521
```

So, how can I get the adapter to use a file that the user owns?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and I think it is a **cross browsing** problem. Something related with opening the **index.html** file directly in the explorer instead through a server because I think the file loader is using server calls with AJAX.

```
OPTIONS file:///todos net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
    ...
    DS.RESTAdapter.DS.Adapter.extend.ajax
    ...
```

Try to launch your site using a server. This works for me.

If you need a fast server and you have installed PHP, you can try opening a terminal and navigating to the folder where your **index.html** is inside (`cd ..../todomvc` or so) and execute the following command:

```
$ php -S localhost:5000
```

This will start a simple server in **http://localhost:5000** and if you navigate to the URL in your browser all should work as a charm.

Answer (score 0):

This Question is some months ago, but perhaps my solution helps somebody.

If you add to your RESTApplication Adapter the correct namespace, you could set the path to the right directory:

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    namespace: 'Ember/webshop'
});
```